# How to save image or video from UIPickerViewController to document directory?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

1. Handle selected image or video:

   ```
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
       print("ok")

       if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
           //what to do to save that image
       } else {
           //how to get the video and save
       }
   }
   ```
2. Save it to the document directory:

   ```
   let path = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
   let newPath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image.jpg") //or video.mpg for example
   ```

How to save that image to following `newPath`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **Use following steps to save Image to documents directory**

**Step 1**: Get a path to document directory

```
let path = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
```

**Step 2**: Append FileName in path

```
let newPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
```

**Step 3**: Decide filetype of Image either JPEG or PNG and convert image to data(byte)

```
//let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) // if you want to save as PNG
let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)   // if you want to save as JPEG
```

**Step 4**: write file to created path

```
let result = jpgImageData!.writeToFile(newPath, atomically: true)
```

Add above code into your `didFinishPickingImage` function.

- **Use following func to save video to documents directory**

  ```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) 
  {
      // *** store the video URL returned by UIImagePickerController *** //
      let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL

      // *** load video data from URL *** //
      let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)

      // *** Get documents directory path *** //
      let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]

      // *** Append video file name *** //
      let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/videoFileName.mp4")

      // *** Write video file data to path *** //
      videoData?.writeToFile(dataPath, atomically: false)
  }
  ```

Comment: Can I do the similar thing for video? please update your answer with video example.

Comment: yes @BartłomiejSemańczyk it can be, i will update my answer. but you need to use video picker and its delegate for the same. same delegate method will not work.

Comment: the last thing, how do we know what extension is that video? Can we differ that casting it from `mediaInfo`?

Comment: it will be `.mp4` video only if its stored in iOS device, though you can find it from UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL in `mediaInfo` dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

Updating the accepted answer to Swift 3 in Xcode 8.3.3

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
        let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        do {
            try jpgImageData!.write(to: newPath)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    } else {
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
        let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: videoURL as URL)
        let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("/videoFileName.mp4")
        do {
            try videoData?.write(to: newPath)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
            print("No image found")
            return
        }
        // saving to application directory
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            print("Image Save to path \(imagePath)")
            try? jpegData.write(to: imagePath)
        }
     }
```