# imagePickerController: Save video to play again on a subsequent run of the app

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller, userdefaults

In my app, the user chooses a video from their library using the built-in `UIImagePickerController`. I can retrieve the URL and play the chosen video. This works great.

However, I also want to be able to play the same video at a later time, after the user has quit and restarted the app, without the user having to reselect it with the picker. I cannot figure out a way to do this. I have tried to use both `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` and `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`. They both work when I play the video immediately. I tried saving those URLs in `userDefaults`, and retrieving them the next time that I run the app. I properly retrieve the URL, but the video does not play with AVPlayer. I expected this behavior for `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` because that appears to be a temporary URL, but I did not expect this for `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.

I have also tried using `PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: <#T##[URL]#>, options: <#T##PHFetchOptions?#>)` but this does not return any values.

How can I save a reference to the video, or the video itself for later use?

Comment: You can copy the video to document directory or cache folder and save the "relative url" to user defaults.

Comment: Can you post some code that shows how to do this?

Comment: Use this answer to save the video https://stackoverflow.com/a/33916860/1244597

Comment: This one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36536044/swift-video-to-document-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from AamirR and Max9xs on my question above, the solution that I chose to implement was to move the file from the TMP directory to the Documents directory. Then play the video from the Documents directory. This also avoids the problem of having the TMP directory fill up with videos every time that the user selects a new one using the imagePickerController.

The following code in the delegate function will move the file:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String
    if  mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String) {

        let TMPvideoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL
        let TMPvideoPath = TMPvideoURL.path

        let manager = FileManager.default
        let documentsDirectory = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!
        let docVideoURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("selectedLibraryVideo.mov")
        let docVideoPath = docVideoURL.path

        do {
            if manager.fileExists(atPath: docVideoPath) {
                try manager.removeItem(atPath: docVideoPath)
            }
            try manager.moveItem(atPath: TMPvideoPath, toPath: docVideoPath)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    photoLibraryPickerController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

And then I can subsequently play the video through a reference to the file path in Documents folder. This works great.

```
        let documentsDirectory = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!
        let docVideoURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("selectedLibraryVideo.mov")
        let docVideoPath = docVideoURL.path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, it works for me:

```
private func loadVideo(url: URL, saveUrl: Bool = false) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }

    guard saveUrl else { return }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "keyVideoUrl")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

To have permissions in order, add following in `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message description in here</string>
```

Now request permission and launch the video picker:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] (status) -> Void in
    guard status == .authorized else { return }

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]

    self?.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Finally use this `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method:

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        guard let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset else { return }

        PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(),
                                                resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void in
            if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                self.loadVideo(url: urlAsset.url, saveUrl: true)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Once you chose a video and its played, you can restart the app and try replaying, like so:

```
if let url = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "keyVideoUrl") {
    self.loadVideo(url: url)
}
```

Here is complete working source [ViewController.swift](https://gist.github.com/r-aamir/742247323d3683e5ed8fd9afa3cd97e4)

Comment: The problem is that when I get a URL from the `UIImagePickerController`, that URL is only valid during that time when I'm running the app. The next time that I run the app, the URL no longer works.

Comment: I can confirm that this is working, you can save the URL in UserDefaults and replay the video on next app start, I have created a ViewController that you can launch and check it out, gist URL https://gist.github.com/r-aamir/742247323d3683e5ed8fd9afa3cd97e4